# Event triggering only when breakpoint is present

Tags: c#, debugging, events, tooltip

I have a weird problem that I would like to solve. I have a project where I want a tooltip window to be shown. For this tooltip, I'm using ToolTip.OwnerDraw = true because I want to draw a picture in the tooltip.

The tooltip is used on a TreeView Node, on the NodeMouseHover event. I then call `ToolTip`. Show from there.

From my understanding, the following should be happening in that order:

`NodeMouseHover` happens and ToolTip. The show is called `Tooltip_Popup` and should happen `ToolTip_Draw` happens.

For debugging purposes, I've put a `Debug.Print` in the `ToolTip_Popup` event and if I run the code normally (in debug mode, but with no breakpoint), the `Debug.Print` never happens (ToolTip_PopUp is never called). If I put a breakpoint on the ToolTip.Show call and then follow execution with F11, the PopUp event is called. Do you know why?

I tried changing the order around, but in any case, the PopUp event is only triggering when using the F11 debugging method, otherwise, it's not called...